# Where in code is the best place to do a core data save?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application that is mainly a heirachy. Object A has many object B's and Object B has many Object C's.

I display them in my iOS application via a navigation type application, and A is on the front page, you push to the B's and push to the C's.

I want to be able to save each instance of my A, B, C objects (which are custom classes) but I'm not too sure when to save and read them as the table view displaying data about A, B and C need to be populated when/before that view is pushed.

Should I be reading it out in didSelectRowAtIndexPath? or something else? and what about saving? should that take place during tapping back or some other place? in the class itself perhaps?

Sam

Comment: I imagine your objects are not large and people can't tap pages back and forth too fast, so you should be able to save things very often, meaning on every push and pop, at least, or even on every edit (every time a value changes). But also don't forget to save when your app goes to background, screen lock or home button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably save whenever the user finishes an edit.

You should get your B's once you need them, etc. When the user taps on a row in the table view that displays all the A's, then get the B's that relate to that particular A object. You have two options here: (1) Fetch them with an `NSFetchRequest` / `NSFetchedResultsController` or (2) traverse the A object's to-many relationship that points to the B objects for that A objects.

As for saving: Note that saves might take a while if you've edited a lot. There are some advanced techniques you can use with iOS 5 with nested contests (`-parentContext`) which allow you to save on a different (non-main) thread. You have to make sure, though, that your safe completes before you're suspended, because the system is allowed to kill your process while you're in the background.